# Odd Transmission slip

Tags: automatic-transmission

My transmission gets these odd slips every once in a while. For example,

today I was driving slow through town, I believe in second gear, and my foot was very light on the pedal. As I release the pedal, It feels like the computer thinks I am want to slow down rather than coasting, and it will initiate a downshift(I think)

The problem though, is that i may be coasting, and I put my foot back on the pedal right as the computer decides to downshift, and this can cause a slip.

I dont know that this is going on, but thats what it feels like. Is this normal? Its a 4 speed, corolla 2012. It feels like it thinks I want to slow  down, but then tried put my foot back on the pedal accelerate at the exact moment of the downshift.

Other Than the miscalculation, it drives fine. Im just worried about whether its my driving style, or the transmission, or the transmisson computer.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: What kind of maintence are you doing? Have you changed the transmission fluid recently? Checked it?

Comment: It is a sealed transmission and I flush it every 40,000 miles, currently at 62,000 and will flush at 80,000

Comment: So fluid is at spec and no visible leaks? And you used dex III OR  the equivalent?

Comment: Also you said sealed? I think you need to replace the filter element... Look under the transmission do you see a bolt pattern around the pan? Flushing won't clean the filter or clean the magnet.

Comment: Yes, it's very light. I think that the computer just misunderstood me, or I hope atleast

Comment: The leak is light?

Comment: Changing the filter sounds like a good idea, I don't believe they did that when they flushed it the last time

Comment: The slip is light , when it happens

Comment: I will ask this as I would anyone else (because it is very important here): ***WHAT IS THE YEAR/MAKE/MODEL/TRANSMISSION OF YOUR CAR?*** There is one (at least) vehicle in particular which this could be *exactly* how it's supposed to operate. Give us this information and I might be able to help you out further.

Answer (score 2):

Ok...my suggestion on starting this is.

MUST BE A VERY CLEAN DIRT/DUST FREE AREA
Don't flush ... Start to change the fluid and filter as recommended. When you take down the pan loosen the bolts in a left then right then left order all the way around. Just loosen them.. Go back and slowly open the bolt patter and you will see the pan lowering.. It may be stuck on the gasket but keep a drain pan under it and just tap the pan it should drop. After the fluid is out take the pan all the way off. Change the filter and the ring inside the hole the filter plugs in. Take out the magnet in the pan clean it and replace it. Look at your fluid for any metal or shavings.
I use Vaseline on my pan gaskets thinly to keep it in place for replacement. 
Bolts don't have to be very tight but snug. Let the gasket do its job and don't over tighten it. 
Refill and check with engine warm.